# How do I change the color of a monochrome image with some transparency?

Tags: color, pixelmator, monochrome

I have this image:

[image]

and I want to change it so it looks gray instead of black. My problem is that it has some anti-aliasing, so there are some half-transparent and/or gray pixels on some borders. If I select everything that's black and change it to gray, those pixels end up being much darker than what they should be. And if I was trying to switch to another color, like red, it wouldn't work at all.

This is something I find myself needing quite often, so I'd like to learn how to do it. What's the conceptual way of doing it? and/or how do I do it with Pixelmator?

Answer (score 1):

I did this in Photoshop, but conceptually it should be very similar:

[image: Gray'd!]

Just adjust the brightness. Gray is just a whiter black, and so lightening everything proportionally should give you the results you want.

I did it with the Brightness/Contrast dialog, but you could do it with Levels too. I'd imagine Pixelmator has these features. I checked out the help pages, and [this](http://help.pixelmator.com/#84) looks like your help file for brightness and contrast, and [this](http://help.pixelmator.com/#81) is levels.

If you want to change color, I'd use the Hue/Saturation dialog with the "Colorize" box checked in Photoshop. [Here are what I believe to be equivalent instructions for Pixelmator](http://help.pixelmator.com/#85).

Comment: How would you try to achieve a very specific color, to match other images, without trial and error? Is it possible?

Comment: @J.PabloFernández I do not know if you'd be able to exactly match by inputting a color value. But what you could do instead is fill a layer with the color you want, put it behind the image, and then adjust the hue/saturation/lightness values until your image disappears into the color you want!